# GCP monitoring - disable uptime check

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-monitoring

We created an uptime check for our website in Google Cloud Platform:

[image]

We don't need the uptime check at the moment, but we might need it again in the future. We saw that there is an option to delete it. However, then we will need to re-create it in the future. Does there exist an option to disable uptime check temporarily and then enable it again when needed?

Answer (score 2):

No.

It's a reasonable need.

There's seemingly no way to "hack" an equivalent to disabled either i.e. by having a zero (never) `period` or no `selectedRegions` see [`UptimeCheckConfig`](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/ref_v3/rest/v3/projects.uptimeCheckConfigs#UptimeCheckConfig).

Consider filing a feature request on Google's public issue tracker for [Monitoring](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:187228).

The [list of issues including `uptime`](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:187228%20uptime)

Comment: Thank you for directing me to Google's issue tracker. I created a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/253055401) there.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to disable the Alert Policy that was created along with the uptime check (automatically through the uptime check creation wizard).
This way you keep the other elements in your configuration (including any extra notification channels), while not using them.